# The Prefix "xsi" For Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" Associated With An Element Type "store-inventory" Is Not Bound

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have very less knowledge regarding xml handling as i mostly familiar with json.

Currently I have 2 files one is schema definition and other is the xml file.

1. https://seller.marketplace.sears.com/SellerPortal/s/schema/rest/inventory/import/v7/store-inventory.xsd?view=markup
2. https://seller.marketplace.sears.com/SellerPortal/s/schema/samples/rest/inventory/import/v7/store-inventory.xml?view=markup

When I am trying to validate the xml with xsd using the site (http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) , there is a strange behavior.

When I am putting the direct web urls(xml & xsd file ulr) in the textfields , Its passing the validation.

But when I am copy pasting the same contents in the text areas , I am getting the below errors.

`The Prefix "xsi" For Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" Associated With An Element Type "store-inventory" Is Not Bound.`

I am getting the same error from server while doing an api call also.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Your XML is valid against your XSD.**

- I have confirmed validity using an offline Xerces-J-based validator
  that is highly reliable.
- I have also confirmed validity using the onine form at
  http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html using the
  copy-and-paste XML and XSD string.  I did not receive the error you
  cite.
- The error you cite would normally indicate that
  `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` was declared
  properly, but you have actually declared it properly.

Although this does not explain what you saw, hopefully it'll encourage you to retry and get past whatever mistake you may have been making earlier.